# Is there a name for 'heteroskedasticity' but for shape, skewness or kurtosis of the distribution?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, diagnostic

Heteroskedasticity means that the variance of the residuals changes with respect to input variables. Is there a name for an analogous concept where the shape of the distribution, i.e., skewness, kurtosis, or some other aspects, not only the variance changes?

Also, are there some established procedures to measure this in the data?

Comment: How about "conditionally varying _____,"  where ______ can be variance, skewness, kurtosis, modality, etc. ?

Answer (score 5):

I am no expert on language or greek, I just did some good ol' fashion googling.

'skedastic' derives from (ancient) greek root (to spread/disperse) [σκεδάννυμι](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CE%BA%CE%B5%CE%B4%CE%AC%CE%BD%CE%BD%CF%85%CE%BC%CE%B9) (see McCulloch 1985). Hetero- also derives from a greek root.

Since kurtosis is also based on a greek root ([κυρτός](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CF%85%CF%81%CF%84%CF%8C%CF%82)) you could argue for something like heterokurtosis.

Following this line of thought I would suggest heteroloxotic, heteroloxoticity from [λοξότητα](https://www.techdico.com/translation/greek-english/%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%BE%CF%8C%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%84%CE%B1.html) for skewness

Not quite sure about shape since that is not necessarily a definite statistical term (but rather encompassing things like skewness and kurtosis).

McCulloch", J. Huston (March 1985). "Miscellanea: On Heteros*edasticity". Econometrica. 53 (2): 483. JSTOR 1911250.

Comment: We could consider moving this to https://english.stackexchange.com/ or https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this Q is more appropriate here. I want to know how is this called in the field, and not how it could be called. I mean, I am sure English majors can come up with a better name to, e.g., "missing completely at random" concept, but I would still rather know that this is how statisticians call it than how they could have called it.

Comment: In that case I have not seen any specific term for these. I would say something like "the kurtosis of the distributions varies by group"

Comment: yes that make sense, I think even if would use something like heteroloxotic, nobody would understand it anyway

Comment: If you want to actually model this have a look at [tag:gamlss]

Comment: @rep_ho, I mean at someone point Pearson used heteroskedastic and probably nobody knew what he meant. But you sir are probably no Pearson haha